# Hadoop 1.2.1 plugin for Eclipse Juno: I can't launch the application

Tags: hadoop, eclipse-plugin

I want to use the Hadoop Eclipse plugin to run the WordCount example.

I have the systems: Local: Windows 7, Eclipse Juno (4.2.2), hadoop-1.2.1 unpacked. Remote: Debian 7.1 with the same hadoop version installed and tested.

I followed the instructions found at: http://iredlof.com/part-4-compile-hadoop-v1-0-4-
eclipse-plugin-on-ubuntu-12-10/ and built the plugin on windows machine.

The hadoop is running, tested with hadoop-examples wordcount and with my freshly created WordCount.

What works with the plugin:

- I can create a new MR project
- I can add new MR location (remote in my case)
- I can  browse/upload/download/delete files from DFS,

What doesn't work:

- I cannot run my code (using Run as ... Run to Hadoop). The console writes "ClassNotFoundException: WordCountReducer". The same error can be found in the hadoop job logs.

I exported the jar from my project, copied it on the remote machine and launched hadoop from command line. Everything worked as expected.

I also saw that when manually launching the project on the remote machine, hadoop creates a job.jar in user/.staging directory. When launching the project from Eclipse, this jar is missing.

My question is: How can I run my project from Eclipse plugin?

Thanks

Comment: Have you included **job.setreducerClass** in your job configuration?

Comment: Yes. The code works if it is launched from CLI on the remote machine.

Answer (score 1):

Set the user from your job driver.

```
System.setProperty("HADOOP_USER_NAME", "YourUbuntuUserID");
```

It might work. Try and let me know.

Comment: Thanks, I added it, it doesn't work. I think the "problem" is that the hadoop instance is remote and the eclipse plugin works only on local setup. Later I'll try to put Eclipse on Debian machine.